# PHP function not executing correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, function, forum

I'm building a small PHP forum that allows users to create posts and comment on them. I have a specific function that's supposed to display the number of replies on a post, that for some reason is only displaying zero. I also have a similar function that counts views and it's working perfectly, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

**Here is the function code for the replies:**

```
  function countReplies($cid, $scid, $tid, $mysqli){
$select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT category_id, subcategory_id, topic_id FROM replies WHERE ".$cid." = category_id AND
                                ".$scid." = subcategory_id AND ".$tid." = topic_id");
return mysqli_num_rows($select);
}
```

**And here is how I called it:**

```
<div class = "content">
```

```
disptopics($_GET['cid'], $_GET['scid'], $mysqli);
countReplies($_GET['cid'], $_GET['scid'], $_GET['tid'], $mysqli);

?>
</div>
```

**I'm getting the following error:**

> Notice: Undefined index: tid in C:\xampp\htdocs(A)Book 2.0\Bootstrap\topics.php on line 56
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs(A)Book 2.0\Bootstrap\content_function.php on line 110

I'm pretty sure I defined variable tid, so any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you reversed your column names and the values you are looking for i.e. category_id = $cid.  Also you should sanatize your query.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, it's late and I've been looking at this for a while.

Answer (score 2):

The error says otherwise, but the fact that says "Undefined index" means that is trying to lookup the index `tid` in an array, likely `$_GET`, not the variable `$tid` itself.

When this happens you get an invalid SQL sentence since you are effectively passing nothing to the condition, resulting in a syntax error:

```
"SELECT category_id, subcategory_id, topic_id FROM replies 
 WHERE $cid = category_id AND $scid = subcategory_id AND = topic_id"
```

Note the `subcategory_id AND = topic_id`.

To avoid that, you should always quote your parameters (this will work because of [variable interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)):

```
"SELECT category_id, subcategory_id, topic_id FROM replies 
 WHERE '$cid' = category_id AND '$scid' = subcategory_id AND '$tid' = topic_id"
```

You'll still get wrong results, but avoid other cascading errors.

However, you should check if all your required parameters are present *before* calling the function. And while you are at it, you also should [Learn how to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174).

Comment: I tried to apply the changes, but now I'm getting this: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\(A)Book 2.0\Bootstrap\content_function.php on line 109

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 It's trying to use `$mysqli` as a string for whatever reason, as if you swaped the arguments order or quoted the variable. Do you have a stray comma or something ?

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says that $_GET['tid'] has no value:

Notice: **Undefined index: tid** in C:\xampp\htdocs(A)Book 2.0\Bootstrap\topics.php on line 56

Another tips to your script:

1) Never use external variables directly to your SQL query. At MySQLi, always use *real_escape_string* method to filter external SQL injection;

2) It's easier to declare $mysqli as *global* variable, so, you doesn't need to pass it as parameter;

3) You can use *COUNT(*)* MySQL method to count the entries and avoid large data transfer and manipulation.

You can rewrite your code as:

```
function countReplies ( $cid, $scid, $tid)
{
  global $mysqli;

  if ( ! $select = $mysqli->query ( "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Count` FROM `replies` WHERE `category_id` = '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string ( $cid) . "' AND `subcategory_id` = '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string ( $scid) . "' AND `topic_id` = '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string ( $tid) . "'"))
  {
    return false;
  }
  return $select->fetch_assoc ()["Count"];
}
```

This code is secure, and will return *false* if there's any error, or the number of replies found.

Answer (score 1):

You current query:

```
$select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT category_id, subcategory_id, topic_id FROM replies WHERE ".$cid." = category_id AND
                            ".$scid." = subcategory_id AND ".$tid." = topic_id");
```

It should be:

```
$select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT category_id, subcategory_id, topic_id FROM 
replies WHERE category_id = ".$cid." AND subcategory_id =
```

".$scid." =  AND topic_id = ".$tid);

Lastly, look into sanitizing your query.
https://www.shift8web.ca/2015/06/securing-your-mysql-queries-from-sql-injection-in-php/

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It should be parameterized. Otherwise there is danger of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from `$_GET['tid']` are you sure it is set?

`mysqli_num_rows()` is returning that error because if there is fail on the query it returns false.

Check the `$_GET['tid']` that has something acceptable first. 
And i always suggest to try and catch code or atleast confirm the result especially if it is from user input!